# How to turn an export.signup and export.signin into a module.exports?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I'm developing a module which I'm using for passport authentication with ExpressJS, and I came up with this solution to gather all the passports methods I'm using:

```
// passport-controller-js

exports.signup = (passport) => (req, res, next) => {    
  // Authenticate methods ================
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Saving user...
    return res.send({ success : true, message : 'signup succeeded' });
  })(req, res, next);   
};

exports.signin = (passport) => (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, token, info) {  
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }

    req.login(user, loginErr => {
      if (loginErr) {
        return next(loginErr);
      }
      return res.send({ success : true, message : 'signin succeeded' });
    });    
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

But since this module will increase adding more strategies I'm thinking if there is a way to put all of them inside a module.exports like:

```
module.exports = (passport) => {
  function signin(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, token, info) {  
      if (err) {
        return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
      }

      req.login(user, loginErr => {
        if (loginErr) {
          return next(loginErr);
        }
        return res.send({ success : true, message : 'signin succeeded' });
      });    
    })(req, res, next);
  };
```

I know that dosn't work Im just wondering if there is a possible solution like that so when I need to require those methods on my router file for example I can do this:

```
  // auth.js (passport is passed from index.js)
  const passportController = require('../controllers/passport-controller')(passport);
  // Process the signup form
  router.post('/signup', passportController.signup);
  router.post('/signin', passportController.signin);
```

Instead of:

```
  // auth.js (passport is passed from index.js)
  const passportController = require('../controllers/passport-controller');
  // Process the signup form
  router.post('/signup', passportController.signup(passport));
  router.post('/signin', passportController.signin(passport));
```

As you can see is just matter of looking for the most legible way to code and keep it simpler as possible.

Any help would be appreaciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to make a module that exports a single function which returns an object. The syntax for that is

```
module.exports = passport => ({
  signup(req, res, next) {
    …
  },
  signin(req, res, next) {
    …
  }
});
```

Comment: Remove parentheses around exported function. Also fix `signup` and `signin` functions declaration.

Comment: @alexmac No, it really works and does what I said. There are no parenthesis around a function, and `signup` and `signin` are not declarations.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks @Bergi :)